# Differential area for the lateral surface of frustum of a cone

Tags: area

I am studying Fluid Mechanics and I needed a differential area element of the side or lateral surface of a frustum. This frustum is cut from a cone. In solution manual of the book I study, differential area is given for side surfaces by $$ dA=2\pi r dz$$

The geometry and the coordinate axes are given in the picture:
                   https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj2Ag.jpg

Please ignore SAE 10W oil and remaining parts other than the frustum. They are something to do with mechanical engineering

Can you give me a hint on how to write the equation above? Do I need to consider the unfolded frustum and draw a differential curved strip element or something?

Answer (score 0):

For a rotational surface around the $z$-axis you need the function $z\mapsto \rho(z)$ that gives the radius of the latitude circles at height $z$. The area element then is
$${\rm d}A=2\pi\>\rho(z)\>\sqrt{1+\rho'^2(z)}\>dz\ .$$
In the case at hand the function $\rho(z)$ increases linearly from $d$ to $D$, hence  $\rho'(z)$ is constant. In fact
$$\sqrt{1+\rho'^2(z)}={1\over\cos\alpha}\ ,$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between the frustum generators and the $z$-axis.

Comment: For $\rho (z)$, z is the independent variable and $\rho$ is the dependent variable,  but how that arc length $\sqrt{1+\rho(z)'^2}$  is represented in $dA=2\pi rdz$?

Comment: The formula $dA=2\pi r dz$ is just for a cylinder with vertical walls. In this case $\rho'(z)\equiv0$.